# My server has been compromised; how do I delete these files that the attacker left behind?

Tags: centos

My vps was hacked and hacker created alot of symbol link in directory.

I try with FileZilla to delete this directory but not work

I try with SSH and use rm but not work too.

Please help how to remove all symbol link and this directory.

Regards

[image]

Comment: Reinstall. Once you have been hacked, you can't really be certain that you have completely regained control of the OS anyway...

Comment: thanks jasonwryan. I will reload OS. But would you help me how to delete these file ?

Comment: run `rm` command with absolute path, but be careful... It's better to upload trusty `rm` command again and execute it with full path...

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 5):

Jasonwryan is right. Don't try to fix it, you can never be sure that it's clean. Back up your data files and reprovision it.

Comment: Thanks bahamat. I will reload OS. But would you help me delete these files ? I want o delete it

Comment: @Yuzike If you backup and restore only what you want to keep, the reprovisioning will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to create undeletable files with `chattr(1)`, including setting it inmutable. See `lsattr(1)`. Other ways to do this include fooling around with SELinux, but I don't think a run-of-the-mill attacker will use it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to login via cpanel/whm with cpanel/whm username and password.

1. Go to file manager.
2. Find the path and delete the files.
3. Enable CSF (Config Server Firewall) plugin and configure firewall rules. So it can secure your VPS server from hacking.

Comment: You cannot be certain that whoever dropped these files didn't also drop other goodies to come back for. Hence, trying to secure the system now is rather like closing the stable door after the horses have run away.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$ find -type l
```

To find all symlinks, then use `-delete` to remove them. But earlier comments are probably right.  Better to remove the whole directory and recreate from a backup.